# How to evenly portion chapati dough?

Tags: bread

A major part of our diet is wheat chapatis/Indian bread.

After we knead the dough for our chapatis, what apparatus or mechanism can we use to ensure that the pieces we use for making individual chapattis are of exactly same size/shape/weight?

Comment: Weight is much more accurate than estimating volume or size. You could add or remove small pieces to adjust.

Answer (score 7):

Even portions means same weight: a scale is the tool of choice here.

Bakers that want equal sized products just weigh the individual portions, then proceed from there.

The shaping / rolling of chapatis was already discussed in [this Seasoned Advice post](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24846/how-to-make-chapattis-round-and-of-same-thickness). Or you could use a [press<sup>1</sup>](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B019RIMTRC) to shape them.

If you are thinking of a larger scale of production, there are [hydraulic chapati presses<sup>1</sup>](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Dg7NUApzntI) or even [(semi-)automatic machines<sup>1</sup>](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=KQZe7XOz4I0) on the market, that shape chapatis of the same thickness out of equal sized (*= weighed!*) portions.

---

<sup>1</sup> No affiliation or recommendation, just random samples from the Internet!

Answer (score 2):

When I'm trying to portion things evenly, I start dividing the sough into parts ... then smaller parts, etc.

So, for the dough I would :

1. make it into a ball
2. try to cut it into two or four equal parts, depending on the size.
3. roll each of those parts into a log / cylinder.
4. cut each of those in half, thirds, or smaller portions if you're comfortable.  (narrower logs are easier to portion into more parts; it's best to cut in half, then half (or thirds) again, etc.)
5. repeat steps 3 & 4 until you have the desired number of portions.

I typically don't do this all at once.  I might start with a quarter of the dough and portion, shape, and cook it, then move onto the next quarter, so it doesn't dry out too much.